# how to display map overlay from internet directly?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

friends,

i have fixed size for example 20*20 image url coming from webservice.

now i want to display those different images on google map as overlay item so that user could tap on it and see detail.

any one guide me how to achieve this?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own subclass of `OverlayItem` and override `getMarker()`, returning your own `Drawable`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk) demonstrates this.

Comment: no in this example programmer is using drawable folder predefined images not downloading from internet. :(

Comment: @UMAR: I never said that it demonstrated "downloading from internet".